# jQuery override opacity on an image with opacity set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image with an inline opacity set like so...

```
<img id="theImage" style="opacity: 0.54;" src="...source..." class="gray-scale-img profileImage img-responsive"/>
```

I'm using IonRangeSlider to set a new value of the opacity but the issue is that if I go above 0.54 on my range slider the opacity does nothing. It will adjust fine from 0.00 to 0.54, but if I go above this, it just remains at 0.54 and will not get any brighter.

```
$("#theImage").css({ opacity: opacity });
```

IonRangeSlider

```
$("#formElement").ionRangeSlider({
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  onChange: function(data) {
    var val = data.from;
    if (val < 100) {
      if (val < 10) {
        var opacity = "0.0" + val;
      } else {
        var opacity = "0." + val;
      }
    } else {
      var opacity = "1.0"
    }
    $("#theImage").css({
      opacity: opacity
    });
  },
  onFinish: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no id to that image at all?

Comment: I adjusted my code for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `if else`

Determine opacity directly `opacity = val/100`

**EDIT**: See the code below you'll get the idea. Also you can look at @gyre 's answer which has similar implementation with `IonRangeSlider` so i'll let this code remain more general.

```js
$(function(){
      var slider = $("#slider");
      var img = $("#theImage");
  
  slider.change(function(){
      var opacity = (this.value)/100;
      img.css("opacity",opacity);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input id="slider" type="range" id="myRange" value="54"><br>
<img id="theImage" style="opacity: 0.54;" src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too many unnecessary calculations and branches with the `opacity` variable. It looks like you are trying to turn a percent into a decimal. Simply use `data.from / 100` as your opacity value.

```js
$("#formElement").ionRangeSlider({
  min: 0,
  from: 54,
  max: 100,
  onChange: function (data) {
    $("#theImage").css('opacity', data.from / 100);
  },
  onFinish: function() {
    // stuff
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="formElement" type="text" >
<img id="theImage" src="//stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico">

<!-- Resources necessary for the demo to work -->
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/static/css/ion.rangeSlider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/master/js/ion.rangeSlider.min.js"></script>
```

---

Edit: According to the documentation, you can configure your slider with the `from` property to set a default position. Credit to [zer00ne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2813224/zer00ne) for using this concept in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42592038/7256039) first.